# Has Any one worked with Azure Event Hub new Data Generator which is in Preview

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-eventhub

I am trying to view data in Azure Event Hub that I generated with the new Azure Event Data Generator - I say 'new', because its' in preview.

When I attempt to view the data in Databricks with I get the message that no data is returned

```
connectionString = 'Endpoint=sb://myspace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=myaccesspolicy;SharedAccessKey=lfZTLixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxhYmIXVaNv9wRM+AEhJ3XsFc=;EntityPath=carlshub'

ehConf = {}

# For versions before 2.3.15, set the connection string without encryption
# ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = connectionString

# For 2.3.15 version and above, the configuration dictionary requires that connection string be encrypted.
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()
df = df.withColumn("body", df["body"].cast("string"))
display(df)
```

I am attempting to generate dummy data using Event Hub' Data Generator as shown in the image.
[image]

However, my code (above) in Databricks cannot see the data

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Aside from that: there really isn't enough info to go on. Please edit to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @DavidMakogon, thanks for getting in touch. I have updated the question. Hopefully, there is enough for you to help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After selecting the weather data, you need to click on the  **send**  button to generate data.

[image]

Make sure you're sending the data at the source.

**Output**

[image]

If the sent data is still yielding no results when you run the code, it's due to the  **enqueuedTime**.

```
import json
from datetime import datetime as dt

endTime = dt.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")

endingEventPosition = {
  "offset": None,        
  "seqNo": -1,              
  "enqueuedTime": endTime,
  "isInclusive": True
}

ehConf["eventhubs.startingPosition"] = json.dumps(endingEventPosition)
```

If you generate data first and then run the code with the above option, you will get no results.

So, make sure to choose the correct option and generate source data properly.